# List of hyperlinks hidden below image

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, html-lists

Essentially I'm trying to get an image to disappear and reveal a list of hyperlinks. I thought I had everything sorted until I realised, that my top image never actually disappears, so none of my hyperlinks are clickable.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#textdiv_violet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 64px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#textdiv_violet img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#textdiv_violet img:hover {
  opacity: .1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
          transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="textdiv_violet">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">I will be violet links</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Me too</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">And me</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding `display: none` to my CSS, but this caused the image to kind of flicker, as the mouse was moved around the area, rather than just disappearing as I had hoped. Hoping for a CSS or HTML solution if possible. Also, this set-up is being designed to work almost exclusively on IE8. If relevant, this code is replicated in 5 other areas around the page.

Please post your answers as if you were speaking to a labrador? I don't code, I've just been given a task that I'm trying to achieve, and whilst ideally I should teach myself CSS and/or HTML, unfortunately I haven't been given the time to do so. Also, apologies if the code looks clumsy, I've pieced it together from basics/forums/tutorials/trial & error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SimianAngel's answer is good work !
but maybe you wanna play with z-index property !
It can prevent image's opacity to 0
and remain watermark effect

just modify your css:

```
     .container { 
        position: relative; 
        width: 400px; 
        height: 400px;
     }

     #textdiv_violet{ 
         position: absolute; 
         top: 160px; 
         left: 64px;
         width: 200px; 
         height: 200px;
     }

     #textdiv_violet:hover img{ 
        opacity: .1; 
        z-index:2;
        transition: z-index .4s ease-out ,  opacity .4s ease-out; 
     }

     #textdiv_violet ul {
        position: relative; 
        z-index: 4
     }

     #textdiv_violet img { 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0px; 
        left: 0px; 
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px; 
        z-index: 6;
     }
```

here's a demo:
    https://codepen.io/Carr1005/pen/jAxBzE

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was after, and I was able to extrapolate it to my other instances. I'm off to read up about the z-index now!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use `transition` with the `display` property of your image.  However, you *can* transition its margin.  Adjusting the image's `margin-left` property after a brief delay (during which you adjust its `opacity` to 0) should do the trick:

```
#textdiv_violet:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -999em;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, margin-left 0s linear .2s;
}
```

Here's a CodePen to illustrate:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzZpmx

Answer (score 0):

what he meant like this
I added that there was an animated `transition` when the image on hover the link will come out

DEMO HERE https://jsfiddle.net/381e8wng/